# How to remove/skip <class 'NoneType'> object in Python

Tags: python, json, iteration, nonetype, zeep

I am receiving the data from SOAP API call from a vendor and using Zeep library. The data is `class 'NoneType'` that is impossible to iterate through. My task is to remove/skip the `NoneType object`.

If I receive a response that contains some values, I am able to jsonify it, however, if the response returns None - I can't jsonify it or remove it.

For instance, I passed two lists of parameters and received two responses back, one that contains the data, the other one is None.
My code below:

```
# Making a SOAP call and save the response
response = client.service.GetOrders(**params[0])

# convert the response object to native Python data format
py_response = helpers.serialize_object(response)

# jsonify (list of dictionaries)
response_list = json.loads(json.dumps(py_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))

print(type(response_list)) 
print(response_list)
```

So the output is the following:

```
<class 'list'> # successfully converted 
[{'AgentID': 0, 'AgentName': 'Not specified', 'CustomerID': 1127}] 
<class 'NoneType'> # was not converted 
None
```

I have tried:

```
clean_response_list = [x for x in response_list if x != None]
```

Error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clean_response_list = [x for x in response_list if x != None]`

This doesn't work because response_list is None, so you can't iterate over it.

Try:

```
response_list = response_list or []
```

Or

```
if response_list is None:
    response_list = []
```

Or

```
if py_response is not None:
    response_list = json.loads(json.dumps(py_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))
else:
    response_list = []
```

Or

```
if py_response:
    response_list = json.loads(json.dumps(py_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))
else:
    response_list = []
```

Comment: However, I'd probably move the check up slightly.
`print(py_response)` to see what it looks like. Then edit your code to check it is valid then create response_list and do the stuff.

Comment: That is not answering anything actually. It's just an if statement, which I tried every which way. And if I did check py-response, it is exactly what the output is in my answer. data and None. And yes, obviously, I need to edit my code to check the validity of the data - this is the exact question I asked.

Comment: You have printed response_list, not py_response

Comment: The output is the same for both.

Comment: `if response_list is None:
    response_list = []` This dis the trick finally! I have accepted the answer! Thanks for the help.